# Neo4j ver. 4.1.1 Cypher Syntax Error "USING PERIODIC COMMIT"

Tags: neo4j, cypher, cql

From  [neo4d lessons learned example from NASA](https://neo4j.com/blog/nasa-critical-data-knowledge-graph/?ref=blog)

References a github project showing how NASA used Neo4J to create a lessons learned database. It is from 2015 and I've been struggling to get the Cypher code running on newer versions of Neo4j (I'm learning as I go).

The error message I am getting is
[image]
My modified version is below.

```
MATCH (n)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n)-[r]-()
DELETE n,r;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Users/kevin/Neo4j/doctopics-master/data/llis.csv' 
AS line
WITH line
Limit 1
RETURN line

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///Users/kevin/Neo4j/doctopics-master/data/llis.csv' AS line
WITH line, SPLIT(line.LessonDate, '-') AS date
CREATE (lesson:Lesson { name: ToInteger(line.`LessonId`) } )
SET lesson.year = ToInteger(date[0]),
   lesson.month = ToInteger(date[1]),
   lesson.day = ToInteger(date[2]),
   lesson.title = (line.Title),
   lesson.abstract = (line.Abstract),
   lesson.lesson = (line.Lesson),
   lesson.org = (line.MissionDirectorate),
   lesson.safety = (line.SafetyIssue),
   lesson.url = (line.url)
MERGE (submitter:Submitter { name: toUpper(line.Submitter1) })
MERGE (center:Center { name: toUpper(line.Organization) })
MERGE (topic:Topic { name: ToInteger(line.Topic) })
MERGE (category:Category { name: toUpper(line.Category) })
CREATE (topic)-[:Contains]->(lesson)
CREATE (submitter)-[:Wrote]->(lesson)
CREATE (lesson)-[:OccurredAt]->(center)
CREATE (lesson)-[:InCategory]->(category);
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///Users/kevin/Neo4j/doctopics-master/data/topicCategory.csv' AS line
MATCH (topic:Topic { name: ToInteger(line.Topic) })
MATCH (category:Category { name: toUpper(line.Category) })
CREATE (topic)-[:AssociatedTo]->(category)
;


// Topic, Correlation.
// Adds a relation to each topic using their correlation
// as a property of the relationship

// Load.
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///Users/kevin/Neo4j/doctopics-master/data/topicCorr.csv' AS line

MATCH (topic:Topic), (topic2:Topic)
WHERE topic.name = ToInteger(line.Topic) AND topic2.name = ToInteger(line.ToTopic)

MERGE (topic)-[c:CorrelatedTo {corr : ToFloat(line.Correlation)}]-(topic2)
;


USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///Users/kevin/Neo4j/doctopics-master/data/topicTerms.csv' AS line
MATCH (topic:Topic { name: ToInteger(line.Topic) })
MERGE (term:Term { name: toUpper(line.Terms) })
CREATE (term)-[r:RankIn {rank : ToInteger(line.Rank)}]->(topic)
;

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS
FROM 'file:///Users/kevin/Neo4j/doctopics-master/data/topicLabels.csv' AS line
MATCH (topic:Topic { name: ToInteger(line.Topic) })
SET topic.label = line.Label
```

;

The original Cypher code and data is in [David Meza's Repo](https://github.com/davidmeza1/doctopics%20https://codeload.github.com/davidmeza1/doctopics/zip/master)

I'd just like to get something ready to demo to our company tomorrow morning to 'sell' the 'lessons learned' and usage of a graph database. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
DELETE n,r
```

on line 3?

Btw purging a store could also be done like this, which is probably faster.

```
MATCH (n)
DETACH DELETE n
```